# Jquery UI dialog not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Hi Im using Jquery UI dialog in my page it is not working in my page in on click,

The code as follows,

```
$( "#actual-hours-dialog-entry" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable : false,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',     
    width: 400,
    close: function() {
        $(this).empty();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();               
        }, 100);
    }
});     

$('#actual-hours-dialog-list').empty(); // code formatting
$('#actual-hours-dialog-list').append(content);

$('#actual-hours-dialog-list').dialog('open');
```

The content appends to the div and displaying in bottom ,But the dialog not opening.

In the same page i have another dialog.It working fine

Anyone please help,Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have duplicate id in the page?

Comment: It seems like the JS is running correctly if the content appends to the div. Have you included the jQuery UI CSS on your page?

Comment: what is your friend the console saying?

Comment: ya im using jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js and its CSS

Comment: It's working in console

Comment: Have you added this in document ready?

Comment: I tried that also not works...

Comment: You will need to share the HTML code.

Comment: The div is not written directly in HTML.its loaded from the python code as Transformer('//div[@id="altlinks"]').after(tag.div(id="actual-hours-dialog-list", title='Actual Hours for Ticket - %s' % data['ticket'].id)).after(tag.div(id="actual-hours-dialog-entry", title='Actual Hours for Ticket - %s' % data['ticket'].id))

Comment: just check whether css is loaded correctly for the div which is displayed in the bottom,usually with position as absolute and top  n bottom with some values

Comment: I dont have position attribute for the div

Comment: it should be there otherwise it wont render like a dialog,add Position:absolute;top:100px;height:100px; to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you need, but using

```
$('#actual-hours-dialog-list').dialog();
```

instead of

```
$('#actual-hours-dialog-list').dialog('open');
```

makes the dialog works.

Also your dialog options are related to a div#actual-hours-dialog-entry, instead of the div#actual-hours-dialog-list you try to open.

Maybe this should be a comment but my reputation is not high enough.

Hope it helps.